# On Text while in private query?

Tags: irc, mirc

i was wondering how to get my remotes scripts to work in private queries rather than a channel, thank you! 
example:

```
on $*:text:*abc*:"username": { msg "username" you whispered, $2 . }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From here: http://en.wikichip.org/wiki/mirc/on_event#Target

> The target parameter of the event defines the locations of where the
>   event can be triggered from. For example, the on text event can be
>   triggered by a channel message or by a query.
>
> `? - defines query location`
>   `# - defines channel location`
>   `* - defines both query and channel locations`
>   `%var - A variable containing a channel or a list of channels is also
>   acceptable`

In your example you would do:

```
on *:text:*abc*:?: { if ($nick == NAME) { msg $nick you whispered, $2 . } }
```

Comment: Genius dude, always helping! By the way, after forwarding the parseline on my last post to query, this now works as a solution!